# How can I import/export bookmarks from chrome and use in another browser?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

I am looking for a way to import/export all bookmark from the Chrome browser for use in Firefox, or potentially other browsers.

Comment: can i use with other browser like opera,safari?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to install anything to export bookmarks from Chrome because  exporting bookmarks functionality is built-in in Chrome. After the Chrome bookmarks have been exported to an HTML file, the bookmarks can be imported from the HTML file to Firefox, Safari, Opera or another web browser.

#### Export bookmarks from Chrome

1. In the top-right corner of the browser window, click the Chrome menu **⋮**
2. Select *Bookmarks* -> *Bookmark Manager*.
3. In the Bookmark Manager menu bar click *Organize*.
4. From the dropdown menu select *Export bookmarks to HTML file...*

#### Import bookmarks to Firefox from HTML file

1. Open Firefox.
2. From the Firefox menu select *Bookmarks* -> *Show All Bookmarks* to open the **Library** window.
3. From the toolbar in the Library window, click *Import and Backup* and from the dropdown menu choose *Import Data from HTML...*
4. In the new **Import Bookmarks File** window that opens, browse to the location of the HTML file that you exported from Chrome.
5. Click the *Open* button.
6. To rearrange the order in which the bookmarks are displayed select *Bookmarks* -> *Show All Bookmarks* to open the **Library** window and drag the bookmark files and folders to their new positions.

#### Import bookmarks to Safari from HTML file <sup>[*](https://www.wikihow.com/Import-Bookmarks-to-Safari)</sup>

1. Open Safari.
2. Locate your bookmarks file.
3. Click *File* in the upper left-hand corner of your screen.
4. Select *Import From*, then click *Bookmarks HTML File*.
5. Locate and select your bookmarks file.
6. Click *Import*.
7. Refresh your browser by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>. Your bookmarks should now be under your URL bar.

Comment: Thank you it's working Thank you so much