# How to backup my Google Chrome Bookmarks?

Tags: ubuntu, backup

I deleted and installed again Chrome,lost my Bookmarks. In order not to repeat the same mistake again,how can I backup my Bookmarks on Ubuntu? Where can I find them on my filesystem?
I can not find them in `~/.config/google-chrome/Default`

My Interface
[image]

where can I customize settings?

My settings
[image]

Comment: Why not go through the Chrome interface? Customise&Control/Bookmarks/Bookmarks manager/export bookmarks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I import/export bookmarks from chrome and use in another browser?](https://superuser.com/questions/1506662/how-can-i-import-export-bookmarks-from-chrome-and-use-in-another-browser)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To your specific question, I think you should take another look. The Bookmarks file is actually in the directory you mentioned (and I double-checked on my Ubuntu installation, and it's there with all my bookmarks), the file is:

```
~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Bookmarks
```

But in general, the simplest way to back up your bookmarks would be to log in Chrome to your Google account and sync them to Google. This way even after a reinstallation you get your bookmarks right back when you sign in.

You can find the Sync settings in Settings under *You and Google*, or by clicking on the profile icon on the toolbar:
[image]

Comment: Take a look at my Settings,where can I find sync?

Comment: Added to my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the "Export bookmarks" feature within Chrome itself to create a backup file that you can save in a preferred location.